# trouble passing variable

Tags: iphone, xcode, variables, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

HI have a little problem, I want to pass a simple variable between 2 viewcontrollers, I try in this way but I get a null variable.

Controller1.m

```
SecondaVista *secondaVista = [[SecondaVista alloc] init] ;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondaVista animated:YES];
secondaVista.titolo = @"Ciao";
```

Controller2.h

```
NSString *titolo;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *titolo;
```

Controller2.m

```
NSLog(@"%@",self.titolo);
```

where is the mistake?

Comment: Where is SecondaVista defined?

Comment: is SecondaVista the same as Controller2?

Comment: set the other controller's variable before pushing the Navigation Controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try setting the variable before pushing the view.

```
SecondaVista *secondaVista = [[SecondaVista alloc] init] ;
secondaVista.titolo = @"Ciao"; 
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondaVista animated:YES];
```

Where are you logging the variable? I mean in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear where?